# 2 columns (1 static and one dynamic) - how to make dynamic column scroll?

Tags: css

I have static left column and right column on right. The problem is when I have a big image on the right column and I scroll, the image moves over the static div.

Is there a way so when I horizontal-scroll the image, it'll stop at the left div and cut off before it goes over the static div?

```
body {
    height:100%;
}

#left {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#right {
    margin-left:250px;
}

<div id="left">
  stuff here
</div>

<div id="right">
  <img src="http://www.superwasp.org/press_release2/millenium.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: What is autoflow? do you mean overflow? you can add :scoll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's 'overflow' not 'autoflow'. Fix that and then add

```
overflow: scroll;
```

to the right div.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, I agree with the answer :)

Comment: sorry, typed it in wrong. it works! queston... is it possible to make the main window horizontal scroller scroll the right div? instead of it's own scroller inside window?

Comment: @Scott Not exactly. If you want to get fancy you could have javascript scroller that controlled the right div but would appear elsewhere. It would be a little work, and more to the point, would confuse your users. If you're just concerned with the appearance of the scroll bar in your div, look at a javascript scroller because you can style it to look nicer and less obtrusive. I've used this one: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ in the past.